# What does this line in NodeJs mean?

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering what does these require lines in NodeJs mean.

```
 var debug = require('debug')('morgan')
 var deprecate = require('depd')('morgan')
```

I'm going through the `index.js` of `morgan` package in NodeJs. Normally `require` only has one parameter (package).

Comment: Note that `require()` is still only receiving one argument -- `'debug'` and `'depd'`, respectively. The value it returns is being invoked immediately with the other through the 2nd pair of parenthesis -- `'morgan'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` returns what ever was defined in the package. In the cases above they are functions and so the *second* parameter is actually calling the function. If you break it out it would look like this:

```
var debugFunctionFactory = require('debug');
var debug = debugFunctionFactory('morgan');
debug('this is a test debug command');
```

The implementation is easy if the module in question returns a function. And in the case of debug and deprecate it returns a function that returns a function:

```
// Module code:
module.export = function(customName) {
  return function(message) {
    console.log(customName + ': ' + message);
  };
};

// Your code:
var foo = require('module'); // => function
var bar = foo('foobar');     // => function
bar('baz');                  // "foobar: baz"

// More concisely:
var foo = require('module')('foobar');  // => function
foo('baz');                             // "foobar: baz"
```